# ¿Por qué "git diff" no funciona sin antes hacer un "git fetch"?

Tags: git

Cuando yo escribo :

```
git diff master origin/master
```

Lo que se supone hace es comparar lo que tengo en la rama "master" local con lo que tengo en la rama "master" en el server. El comando en sí tiene sentido basándonos en cómo funcionan los flujos de git:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero sin embargo esto no funciona sin antes hacer un:

```
git fetch
```

Que se supone trae los cambios del servidor al repositorio local.

¿Por qué no basta solo la primera sentencia?

Comment: Cuando dices que no funciona si no utilizas `git fetch` antes, te refieres a que lanza algun error?

Comment: Hola Einer, no. Simplemente no muestra nada.

Comment: Pero eso no es el problema q tengo...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21101689/73749 esta respuesta se acerca bastante a lo que te esta pasando. Tendriamos que revisar mejor, pero los cambios en origin en realidad los esta mirando de tu repo, no del servidor, entonces no hay diff que valga. Fetch trae los cambios a tu lado, pero no los comitea a tu master... creo que viene por ese lado, pero estoy leyendo a 4 manos a ver si encuentro la justificacion exacta

Comment: Buena!!! es como medio inconsistente para mi que se emplee el comando "origin" en el DIFF si solo se compara con lo que esta local y no en el remoto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que `git diff` solo funciona en local, es por esto que debes tener primero la "rama" origin/master actualizada (lo cual haces con fetch).

Puedes leer al respecto en [Learn the workings of Git, not just the commands](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/d-learn-workings-git/index.html) <sub>en inglés</sub>.

Recuerda también que `git fetch` solo descarga los últimos cambios del repositorio, no los aplica, así que es seguro hacer `git fetch` antes del `git diff`.

La lectura de [My Git Workflow](https://blog.osteele.com/2008/05/my-git-workflow/) <sub>en inglés</sub> puede ayudar un poco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Así estoy concluyendo pero entonces porque se utilizar la palabra clave "origin" que se supone representa al servidor?

Comment: Vale ten en cuenta que puedes tener varios orígenes de repositorio, por tanto cada "origen" puede tener un nombre, entonces podrías llamar uno "origen" que sería diferente de "origin" entonces al hacer el diff, debes decir explicitamente contra quién estás comparando

Comment: origin es en realidad un alias para el repo externo que estas usando. Pero diff no se conecta al repo externo.

Comment: @JorgeEduardoAdan encontre una imagen que quizas clarifique un poco. si no te molesta la agrego a tu respuesta. si no estas de acuerdo sacala...

Comment: Me parece acertado. Muchas gracias.
Lo que habría que tener claro es que DIFF no compara cambios con el servidor por mas que se le ponga la palabra "origin"

Comment: añado un detalle que creo que estais omitiendo. una cosa es el servidor, y otra lo que tienes en tu equipo. Y en tu equipo puedes tener tus ramas Y una referencia de lo que hay en el servidor. Tienes que ACTUALIZAR tus referencias contra el servidor, para tener tus indices locales al dia. Por eso primero el `git fetch` y luego `git diff`

Comment: Si tienes una rama local `master` y el repositorio remoto tiene también una rama `master`, entonces tu repositorio local tiene también una rama "oculta" llamada `origin/master`, que contiene una copia de la rama remota. Todas las operaciones que hagas contra `origin` las haces contra esa copia local. Esa copia sólo se actualiza con `git pull/fetch` (o con un `git push` que haya tenido éxito, en cuyo caso le añade a la copia los últimos commits que se suban al servidor). Sin `git push` ni `git pull`, la rama "oculta" `origin/master` puede estar desfasada con respecto a la verdadera rama remota.